# Change facebook social discovery description

Tags: facebook

this seems like a fairly simple question, but I just can't figure it out. I recently developed  a facebook game. Now when somebody is playing that game the the message everybody loves is appearing in his stream:

```
Some guy is playing the most awesome game ever.
```

And after that, the is a description, which is the root of my problem. I'd like to change this description, which at the moment is showing ...

```
Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet.
```

Does anybody know where I can change this text? It would also be helpful if somebody could tell me what the term for that text is, so I could do the research on my own.

//Edit: Ok, the term for the particular FB post is `social discovery` or `usage stories`, which unfortunately didn't help me find out how I can change the description of that post. That would be the remaining question.

Comment: Is this coming from the meta tags on your app's landing page?

Comment: I don't think so, because I never entered the text that is being shown `Facebook is a social utility ...` anywhere.

Comment: That looks like the text on the logged-out homepage of Facebook :/